# Auto changing size buttons by css

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a "step manual" for auto-diagnosis but i have a little problem with auto-changing size buttons by (probably) CSS.

When I go click first sequence: Do you have a fever -> yes -> do you have a cough -> go to doctor

Next I click "reset" and do second sequence: Do yo have a fever -> yes -> Do you have a cough... and here buttons are smallest than first time.

Where I make mistake in code?

```
/*buttons*/
#msform .action-button {
width: 100px;
background: #27AE60;
font-weight: bold;
color: white;
border: 0 none;
border-radius: 1px;
cursor: pointer;
padding: 10px 5px;
    margin: 10px 5px;
}
#msform .action-button:hover, #msform .action-button:focus {
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 2px white, 0 0 0 3px #27AE60;
}
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bj8pd5op/30/)

[Screens](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7Bkil.png)

Comment: The jsfiddle link displays something else than what you have described.

Comment: Can you post the HTML too ?

Comment: Oh sorry, wrong link to jsfidlle.. please see now.. 

http://jsfiddle.net/bj8pd5op/30/

Comment: Could you put up your code on JS-Fiddle and then we could probably figure out what the issue is.

Ensure your js code isn't setting your button size with a different value on clicking reset.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The buttons and the container as a whole are shrinking because of a scaling down to **0.8** of their original sizes in your javascript code.

Remove this line from your JS:

```
current_fs.css({'transform': 'scale('+scale+')'});
```

Updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/nashcheez/bj8pd5op/31/

Comment: Thank you so much! Can I have one more question? How to make body (this white field) to auto-scalling to content inside? I delete the widhth 80% in #msform fieldset { but field now is not center...

Comment: From what I understand from the above comment, the `fieldset`s are centrally aligned due to the `text-align: center` irrespective of any fixed width or not.

Answer (score 0):

```
scale = 1 - (1 - now) * 0.2;
```

This causes your whole fieldset to shrink down to 0.8.
You probably added it for the scaling effect.

Two solutions :

- Remove the line (as mentioned by @nashcheez ) or set the scale to 1
- If you want still want the scale effect using css animations to restore the scale back to it's original size ( aka 1 )

  ```
  @keyframe scaleAwayToGlory {
    0% {
        transform: scale(0.8);
    }
    100% {
        transform: scale(1);
    } 
  }
  ```